# C# bot framework exception seem to be not handled properly between the emulator and the web chat test on the botframework website

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, web-chat

So far I have the following code to be used to check whether a LUIS JSON response contains a entity or not

```
public static class StatusHelper
{        
    public static bool EntityCheck(LuisResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            var statuscheck = result.Entities[0].Entity;
            return true;
        } catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And inside another file I used

```
if (StatusHelper.EntityCheck(LuisResult result)) 
{

//code

}
else 
{
    await context.PostAsync("No Entities");
}
```

In my bot emulator, if no entities were found, it would have the bot saying

```
No Entities
```

But on the dev.botframework.com website it would say

```
Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.
```

I'm not sure what's going on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using an Exception throw for testing if there is a value?
Can't you just check is your result and some entities in the array, then check if the 1st entity is not null like the following:

```
public static bool EntityCheck(LuisResult result)
{
    return (result.Entities.Count > 0 && result.Entities[0].Entity != null);
}
```